# Display all posts from parent category and group by child category with headings in Timber/Twig

Tags: php, html, wordpress, timber

I am using the following code to select and set context for a category landing page on my client's website.

**Code**

```
$args = array(
  'cat' => '5,3,4,6',
  'numberposts' => 5,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
);
$context['stories'] = Timber::get_posts( $args );
```

I am using this code to set the template and assign context.

**Code**

```
if( $category->parent == 0 ) {
  // Stories parent category
  $templates = array( 'category.twig' );
  $context['categories'] = $categories;
}
```

This is all working, but I am needing to duplicate the functionality and make the following adjustments.

- Set `numberofposts` to **All**
- Add headings for each of the children categories
- Display all of the posts assigned to each category below the headings

This layout will act like an "all posts" page. This page will be assigned to a menu item called "All Stories".

Is it possible to make this work without having to write lots of additional code? I am learning Timber and Twig as I go, so please feel free to share some tips and tricks for improving my approach.

Answer (score 1):

Set numberofposts to all.

```
 'numberposts'       => -1,
```

Update context toadd headings.

```
$context['title']       = single_cat_title( '', false );
$context['description'] = category_description();
```

Display all of the posts assigned to each category.

```
$cat_id = 1;
$context['category_posts'] = Timber::get_posts(
    array(
        'cat' => $cat_id, 
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    )
);
```

Comment: Better way use, `posts_per_page => -1` instead of the `numberofposts`